# Replace String in occurrence using java

Tags: java, string

I have a string which needs to be replaced by occurrence

My Code:

```
String value="EMPID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,PROJECT,DOMAIN,Work Item $WORKNUMBER$ is assigned to $ASSIGNEDTO$ due to $REASON$,~WORKNUMBER~ASSIGNEDTO~REASON~"

            String[]  value_split = value.split("\\,");
            System.out.println(value_split[6]);
            String template=value_split[6];
            String var=value_split[7];
            String[] bindvar=var.split("~");
            String finaltemplate="";
            for (String string : bindvar) {
                //System.out.println(string);
                String valuefromQueue=getQueueLog(string);
                //System.out.println(valuefromQueue);
                System.out.println(template.replace("$",valuefromQueue ));
            }

public static String getQueueLog(String var) {

    String resval ="";

    if (var == null) {
        return var;
    }

    switch (var) {
        case "WORKNUMBER":
            resval = "12123123";
            break;
        case "ASSIGNEDTO":
            resval = "RM";
            break;
        case "REASON":
            resval = "NEW LC";
            break;
        }

    return resval;
}
```

What I get in  String template =Work Item $WORKNUMBER$ is assigned to $ASSIGNEDTO$   due to $REASON$

And in valuefromQueue=12123123 RM NEWLC

```
Expected  Output should be :Work Item 12123123 is assigned to RM due to NEWLC
```

My output:
Work Item 12123123WORKNUMBER12123123 is assigned to 12123123ASSIGNEDTO12123123   due to 12123123REASON12123123

Comment: `template.replace("$",valuefromQueue )` => You are replacing the "$"s, not the keywords.

Comment: Are the values always in the same order as the keywords? Like `"$key1$ blah $key2$" , "val1~val2"` or can they be randomly ordered like `"$key1$ blah $key2$" , "val2~val1"` ? Or do you know a specific order of the values and keywords can be anywhere in the template?

Comment: I have to replace by $replace string here$..By using $ only because i dont know what is there in between the $

Comment: Well, you cannot. You somehow have to know what to replace with what ...

Comment: @Fildor They are ordered ..I am sure about that

Comment: So, it will always be "Workno~Assignto~reason", right?

Comment: Exactly..They are assigned respectivly

Comment: @user7352962 so you want to replace $??????$ to ~???????~ right ??? and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`template.replace("$", valuefromQueue)`
```

**You are replacing all occurrences of `$`.** Those appear as pre- and postfix of all your placeholders (`$WORKNUMBER$`). The output is exactly what I would expect.

To get the output you desire, you need to specify the exact placeholders, like so:

```
`template.replace("$WORKNUMBER$", valuefromQueue)`
```

Looking at your `getQueueLog()` method, it looks as if `string` contains the placeholder strings (`WORKNUMBER`, `ASSIGNEDTO` and `REASON`) without the dollar signs. Hence, you should be able to use that for `replace()`:

```
`template.replace("$" + string + "$", valuefromQueue)`
```

---

Note: Since you don't seem to be using `valuefromQueue` anywhere else, you can shorten this:

```
for (String string : bindvar) {
    String valuefromQueue=getQueueLog(string);
    System.out.println(template.replace("$" + string + "$", valuefromQueue));
}
```

... to this:

```
for (String string : bindvar) {
    System.out.println(template.replace("$" + string + "$", getQueueLog(string)));
}
```

Comment: I have to replace by $replace string here$..By using $ only because i dont know what is there in between the $

Comment: Well, `string` holds what's between the `$`, no? In which case you could simply do `template.replace("$" + string + "$", valuefromQueue)`

Comment: Great! I added that to the answer - plus some small additional improvement over your code.

Answer (score 1):

You replace isn't good, your template is $keyWord$, so `template.replace("$"+string+"$",valuefromQueue )`